# Python access all entrys from one dimension in a multidimensional numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to manipulate the data of all entries of a complicated 3d numpy array. I want all entries of all subarrays in the X-Y-Position. I know Matlab can do something like that (with the variable indicator : for everything) I indicated that below with DARK[:][1][1]. Which basically mean I want the second entry from the second the column in all sub arrays. Is there a way to do this in python?

```
import numpy

# Creating a dummy variable of the type I deal with (If this looks crappy sorry, the variable actually comes from the output of d = pyfits.getdata()):
a = []
for i in range(3):
    d = numpy.array([[i, 2*i], [3*i, 4*i]])
    a.append(d)

print a
# Pseudo code:
print 'Second row, second column: ', a[:][1][1]
```

I expect a result like this:

```
[array([[ 0,  0],[ 0,  0]]),
array([[ 1,  2],[ 3,  4]]),
array([[ 2,  4],[ 6,  8]])]

Second row, second column: [0, 4, 8]
```

Comment: Use something like `import numpy as np, d = np.arange(12).reshape(2,2,3)` to create the input array? Show us the expected output then?

Comment: That does not produce the same variable as above it produces [[[ 0  1  2] [ 3  4  5]] [[ 6  7  8] [ 9 10 11]]] So no arrays in there. The problem is that I deal with a more complicated source for my variable from fits files which I do not want to elaborate here. The point is my method produces the same type of variable as the fits files I use

Comment: That was a suggestion to create a sample ndarray, as you said - `"I don't know another way to create a multidimensional numpy array"`.

Comment: Ok I edited it, the actual output comes from the function d = pyfits.getdata() and sadly I can't change that. But maybe there is a way to transform the a into something I can process further?

Comment: You can try `np.array(d)` if `d` is not an ndarray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, thanks **Divakar** and **eeScott**:

```
import numpy as np

# Creating a dummy variable of the type I deal with (If this looks crappy sorry, the variable actually comes from the output of d = pyfits.getdata()):
a = []
for i in range(3):
    d = np.array([[i, 2*i], [3*i, 4*i]])
    a.append(d)

# print variable
print np.array(a)
print 'Second row, second column: ', np.array(a)[:, 1, 1]

# Alternative solution:
a = np.asarray(a)
print a
print 'Second row, second column: ', a[:,1,1]
```

Result:

```
[[[0 0][0 0]]
 [[1 2][3 4]]
 [[2 4][6 8]]]
Second row, second column:  [0 4 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using slightly different syntax.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3) # Create a 3x3x3 3d array

print("3d Array:")
print(a)
print("Second Row, Second Column: ", a[:,1,1])
```

Output:

```
>>> 3d Array:
 [[[ 0  1  2]
   [ 3  4  5]
   [ 6  7  8]]

  [[ 9 10 11]
   [12 13 14]
   [15 16 17]]

  [[18 19 20]
   [21 22 23]
   [24 25 26]]]

>>> Second Row, Second Column:  [ 4 13 22]
```

Comment: That does not produce the same type of variable my actual code is:     d = pyfits.getdata(fitsimage)    So I can not change the way I create the variable, but maybe there is a way to change the current a into something I can reshape?

Comment: You don't need to reshape it, I'm just creating an example 3d array with that line of code. Just use "print 'Second row, second column: ', a[:,1,1]"

Comment: Actually in your code you need to change it from a list of numpy arrays to a numpy array of numpy arrays, after your for loop you can put: `a = np.asarray(a)`. Then `print a[:,1,1]` will work.